# Electric field in frame corotating with sun

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics, solar-wind

I am studying [this paper](http://adsbit.harvard.edu//full/1967ApJ...148..217W/0000217.000.html) on the solar wind for a class on MHD, but I am perplexed by the line that precedes equation (5):
"

> But in a perfectly conducting fluid ${\bf v}$ is parallel to ${\bf B}$ in a frame rotating with the Sun, and thus we obtain [...]

For the MHD physicist, perfectly conducting means 
$$\mathbf{E} = -\frac{1}{c}\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$$
but I see no obvious reason why the electric field should vanish in the corotating frame. The matter-of-factness with which this statement is made is making me feel really stupid. Can anyone provide a simple explanation?

Secondly, even if I accept the above statement as fact, I do not understand how equation (5) is even related to it. Equation (5) is
$$ r (u B_\phi - v_\phi B_r ) = \mathrm{const.} = - \Omega r^2  B_r. $$

Where does the expression on the far RHS come from? I'm not even sure which frame they're working in to get this expression, which only begins to make sense to me if $B_\phi=0$ for some reason (but I see no reason for this to be true in either frame).

Comment: Do you accept that $\mathbf{v}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{B}$ in the corotating frame?

Comment: And as for your second question, the expression comes from the expression for centrifugal force in a rotating frame.

Comment: No, I don't see why ${\bf v}$  should be parallel to ${\bf B}$, that's the whole point.

Comment: If we average over cyclotron motions, then particles are pinned to field lines. So the motion of the particles has two components: one parallel to the field lines, and one representing the motion of the field lines themselves. Though I don't know much about astrophysical plasmas, the conclusion the author reaches makes sense if the field lines rotate with the Sun. If you accept that, then moving into a corotating frame eliminates the motion of the field lines, meaning that the particles are now moving parallel to the field.

Comment: I can sort of see your point, but is there a way to argue that $\mathbf{v} \parallel \mathbf{B}$ in the stationary frame of $\mathbf{B}$ using ideal MHD? Say, via freezing in of $\mathbf{B}$ into $\mathbf{v}$?

Comment: I had the "aha!" moment in the shower. I think the point is that in MHD, due to quasineutrality any electric field must be inductive, so in a frame where the magnetic field is stationary, there can be no electric field. Hence by ohm's law $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}=0$

Comment: Ah, right, of course. Surprisingly subtle.

Comment: You can also think of it in the following way:  All the non-relativistic transformations in MHD can be treated as Galilean, thus, $\mathbf{B}' = \mathbf{B}$.  From this, one can see that we can transform into a frame where $\mathbf{v}'$ is entirely parallel to $\mathbf{B}'$.  That is, one can remove all the transverse velocity components.  This is called the de Hoffmann-Teller frame, i.e., where $\mathbf{E}' = 0$.